# How to set 'secure' and 'httponly' cookie in Tornado?

Tags: python, cookies, tornado

I have a Tornado app which uses Google Oauth 2.0 Authentication, gets the email and sets that in a cookie. Now I don't want anyone else to access this cookie, copy the value and get another user's details on my app. So I want to make this cookie `httponly` and `secure` cookie. However when I pass these as arguments its not able to set the cookie:

```
self.set_secure_cookie('trakr', email, secure=True, httponly=True)
```

I am suing Tornado 3.2.2 and Python 2.7.5.

since its not able to set the cookie, it keeps redirecting to google auth page. Here is my code:

```
class GAuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleOAuth2Mixin):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        if self.get_current_user():
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        if self.get_argument('code', False):
            user = yield self.get_authenticated_user(redirect_uri=settings.google_redirect_url,
                code=self.get_argument('code'))
            if not user:
                self.clear_all_cookies() 
                raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, 'Google authentication failed')

            access_token = str(user['access_token'])
            http_client = self.get_auth_http_client()
            response =  yield http_client.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token='+access_token)
            user = json.loads(response.body)
            self.set_secure_cookie('trakr', user['email'], secure=True, httponly=True)
            self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/products"))
            return

        elif self.get_secure_cookie('trakr'):
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        else:
            yield self.authorize_redirect(
                redirect_uri=settings.google_redirect_url,
                client_id=self.settings['google_oauth']['key'],
                scope=['email'],
                response_type='code',
                extra_params={'approval_prompt': 'auto'})
```

The code works perfectly fine when I remove `secure` and `httponly` arguments. It also works if I just send `httponly` argument, however it doesn't seem to set the cookie when I pass both the arguments.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not with Tornado or Python, but with my server as I was not using [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_cookie):

> A secure cookie has the secure attribute enabled and is only used via
>   HTTPS, ensuring that the cookie is always encrypted when transmitting
>   from client to server. This makes the cookie less likely to be exposed
>   to cookie theft via eavesdropping. In addition to that, all cookies
>   are subject to browser's same-origin policy.